# Google Drive v3 | File Append | com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden

Tags: google-drive-api

Creating a new CustomerData.json file in Google Drive successfully.
Next operation is to update the CustomerData.json file.
On execution of the below code:

```
File updatedFile = service.files().update(fileId, file, mediaContent).execute();
```

the application throws the exception with 403: Forbidden.

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable.",
    "reason" : "fieldNotWritable"
  } ],
  "message" : "The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable."
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:432)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at com.app.gdrive.DriveQuickStart.updateCustomer(DriveQuickStart.java:171)
    at com.app.gdrive.DriveQuickStart.main(DriveQuickStart.java:226)
```

Obviously I went thru the Google API documentation and code samples available on the internet, along with the StackOverflow solutions...  still struggling without success.

Create operation - This creates the CustomerData.json file

```
public static final String createCustomer() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException, JSONException {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("Phone", "3023553505");
        jsonObject.put("Name", "Bob Carson");
        jsonObject.put("Business", "Spot Clicks");
        jsonObject.put("Address", "46 Fairytale Dr, Newark");
        jsonObject.put("State", "NJ");
        jsonObject.put("Country", "USA");
        FileWriter jsonFile = new FileWriter("CustomerData.json");
        jsonFile.write(jsonObject.toString());
        jsonFile.close();
        Drive driveService = getDriveService();
        String folderId = "1G9vFaUCsPN6GomJRrK7vML9bSd5Wm63t";
        File fileMetadata = new File();
        fileMetadata.setName("CustomerData.json");
        fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList(folderId));
        java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("CustomerData.json");
        FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("application/json", filePath);
        File file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
            .setFields("id, parents").execute();
        driveService.permissions().create(file.getId(), new Permission().setRole("writer")
                .setType("anyone").setAllowFileDiscovery(false)).execute();
        return file.getId();
    }
```

The CustomerData.json file in the drive looks like below:
[image]

Update **[APPEND]** operation - This fails to update the CustomerData.json file

**EDIT-1** I need to APPEND additional data into the same json file, I'm not trying to update the existing data in the file.

```
public static final String updateCustomer(Drive service, String fileId) {
        try {
                        
            String jsonString = new JSONObject()
                .put("Phone", "9840056987")
                .put("Name", "Rick Smiley")
                .put("Business", "Smiling Bots")
                .put("Address", "6 Country Park, Baltimore")
                .put("State", "MD")
                .put("Country", "USA")
                .toString();        
            File file = service.files().get(fileId).execute();
            System.out.println(file.getName());
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file.getName(), true));  
            writer.newLine();
            writer.write(jsonString);
            writer.close();
            java.io.File uFile = new java.io.File(file.getName());
            FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("application/json", uFile);
            File updatedFile = service.files().update(fileId, file, mediaContent).execute();
            return updatedFile.getId();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return fileId;
    }
```

The SCOPE is defined as

```
List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE);
```

I tried with DRIVE scope as well... also I deleted the  `StoredCredential` file every time I change the SCOPE.

This code is used for the Desktop App, but later I'm planning use in the mobile app as well.

Quick help is appreciated

Comment: What is stored in `File`? If you're retrieving it directly from the API there are a lot of fields which will be returned which are [not writeable](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource). Make sure you're only trying to update fields which are specified in the [request body of `files.update`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update)

Comment: There is one json entry in the file while it gets created 
{"Address":"46 Fairytale Dr, Newark","Phone":"3023553505","State":"NJ","Country":"USA","Name":"Bob Carson","Business":"Spot Clicks"}

As a next step, I'm trying to append the file with additional entry.

Comment: That's not what I mean. You have the line `File file = service.files().get(fileId).execute();`, which will return the file information from the server. This includes all fields, including non-writable ones. You are then passing this file back into `File updatedFile = service.files().update(fileId, file, mediaContent).execute();`. Check that you aren't trying to send the update request with included unwritable fields.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo How do I exclude the unwritable fields?  Because my objective is to append some text (JSON) in the file and update as a newer version.  I'm not doing anything else with it

Comment: @RafaGuillermo Thanks for your guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it resolved - here is the solution

in the updateCustomer() create a new File object like below and use that new object

```
File updateFile = new File();
updateFile.setName(file.getName());
```

Use that `updateFile` object thereafter